# How to integrate React Bootstrap with Gatsby

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to integrate the react-bootstrap Framework with my Gatsby project but I am having the following error on console and nothing is rendering.

I installed it through npm package **"npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap --save"**
and added this in gatsby-browser.js:
**import "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALzZa.png)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the gatsby-browser.js, try this way.

Use main.scss in your Layout.js

```
import '../stylesheets/main.scss';
```

Then in the main.scss call the bootstrap from the node_modules.

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```